# How to refresh knockout grid after AJAX API Call

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am working in an MVC 5  / Knockout environment. My View is loaded initially from the ViewModel supplied by a standard MVC 5 Controller. I have a knockout grid as part of this view. The grid is correctly populated based on the ViewModel contents.

On a user button push, a Web API call is made and returns successfully. I want to use the data returned from the API call to update the Knockout observable array which is bound to the knockout grid. I can see the knockout observable array is correcty updated, but the knockout grid is never refreshed. The knockout observalbe array I write to with the results of the API call is the same array that gets written to when the View is first loaded.

This is teh code at the top of the `.cshtml` view:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var inputData = ko.mapping.toJS(@Html.Raw(HelperFunctions.ToJson(Model)));
        var dom = document.getElementById("AWBSNode");
        var obj = new AreasModel(inputData);
        ko.applyBindings(obj, dom);
    });
</script>
```

`AWBSNode` is the topmost div in my cshtml. Below is the html for my Grid

```
<div id="koGridPanel" class="panel panel-default top-buffer">
     <div class="panel-heading">AWBS - Areas</div>
     <div class="koGrid" data-bind="koGrid: gridOptions"></div>
</div>
```

Below is the relevant JS of my View Model / grid config / binding

```
var AreasModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    var apiCall = new APICaller();
   .
   .
   .
   self.AllAWBSAreas = ko.observableArray(
       ko.utils.arrayMap(data.Areas, function(x) {
          return new NewAWBSAreaModel(x);
       })
   );
  .
  .
  .
  this.gridOptions = {
        footerRowHeight: 35,
        beforeSelectionChange: function (rowItem) {
           self.selectAreaToEdit(rowItem); 
        },
        disableTextSelection: false,
        keepLastSelected: false,
        multiSelect: false,
        displaySelectionCheckbox: false,
        data: self.AllAWBSAreas,
        columnDefs: [
            { field: 'Name', displayName: 'Name' }, 
            { field: 'Description', displayName: 'Description' }
        ]
    };
  .
  .
  .
```

Below is the API Call I make (I am using a wrapper function but that part works fine as I do come in to the success path and the data is there

```
apiCall.CallAPI(
    url,
    dom,
    true,
    null,
    function (successData) {
       self.AllAWBSAreas(ko.utils.arrayMap(successData.Items, function (x) {
           return new NewAWBSAreaModel(x);
       });
    );
```

I also tried the alternative approach of

```
apiCall.CallAPI(
    url,
    dom,
    true,
    null,
    function (successData) {
        self.AllAWBSAreas(successData.Items); 
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

I have tried calling `valueHasMutated()` on the `AllAWBSAreas` entity. There is no problem with the API call and its return data as this pattern works fine in all other aspects of the project. The symptom I see is that the grid in the UI is "affected" but not updated. The tidy blue banner at the top goes blank but the data remains unchanged.

Comment: I took a simpler version of your situation and created this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lhwt7emc/2/ ... your same approach does seem to work there. can you reproduce it on the fiddler?

Comment: Hi Sam, I looked at your suggestion. I modified my setup to try to update my knockout grid with manually generated data as opposed to API Call generated data. The grid updated cleanly with the manual data. I tried another test. I declared in the same view a simple Bootstrap table bound to a separate knockout observable array. I made my original API call and updated the observable array driving the Bootstrap table with the API Call data and that worked fine too. So it's just the knockout grid that won't update in the context of an API call.

Comment: I should also say that I am running with Chrome and in the Developer tools there are no errors appearing when I try to update the knockout observable driving the knockout grid.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be a problem with the ladda spinner.  The knockout grid would not update if the spinner was attached to the knockout grid. I moved the spinner to nearby piece of UI and all worked. Thanks for those who took the time to look at / help with this issue.